# WP REST API Post Status Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest

I am getting my hands dirty in WP REST API. I have gone through a couple of tutorials and have a question using JavaScript to create a new post.

In [this](https://apppresser.com/wp-api-post-submission/) tutorial, the post `var status = 'draft';` (see code). **So I am just worried that won't anyone able to hack that status?**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    $( '#post-submission-form' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $( '#post-submission-title' ).val();
        var excerpt = $( '#post-submission-excerpt' ).val();
        var content = $( '#post-submission-content' ).val();
        var status = 'draft'; // this code

        var data = {
            title: title,
            excerpt: excerpt,
            content: content
        };

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wp/v2/posts',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
                alert( POST_SUBMITTER.success );
            },
            fail : function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
                alert( POST_SUBMITTER.failure );
            }

        });

    });

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Users can always manipulate the data being sent in javascript/jquery requests since it all lives client-side**

It is not possible to ensure what data is coming from a client. This passes the burden to the server to validate each incoming request. The only way to guarantee a user doesn't submit a different value than expected would be to handle that server-side. Anything you do client side can be manipulated by anyone visiting your site.